# Python String Formatter having %

Tags: python, string-formatting

It's simple when the string is something like:

```
s = 'test%s1'
s % 'TEST'
```

However, when `%` itself is present in the string, then I'm getting this error.
eg:

```
s = 'test%s12%34'
s % 'TEST'
>>ValueError: incomplete format
```

How to handel this case ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double the `%`:

```
s = 'test%s12%%34'
```

On output it'll be collapsed again to a single percent symbol:

```
>>> s = 'test%s12%%34'
>>> s % 'TEST'
'testTEST12%34'
```

From the [*String Formatting Operations* documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations), where the various conversion characters are documented:

> `'%'` No argument is converted, results in a `'%'` character in the result.

where the second `%` is the conversion character.

Comment: Cool !!
Can you also explain the reason behind its working ??

Comment: @SaurabhVerma: it is a documented conversion character; `%%` is converted to `%`.